# getting JSON from a spring rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to get only the response Body in format JSON from a Spring Rest Controller, my code is :

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

    public UserInfo getUserDetails(Principal principal){
        return users.get(principal.getName());
    }
```

my Result is :

Response {_body: "{id: 001}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}.

how can i get only the body as Json thank's ....

Comment: try without @ResponseBody it will return only in return page

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Comment: Still getting the same result without ResponBody

Answer (score 3):

Use `@RestController`

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @GetMapping("/userDetails")
    public UserInfo getUserDetails(Principal principal){
        return users.get(principal.getName());
    }

}
```

output:

```
{"id": 001}
```

### Using the `@RestController` Annotation

**Note:**
Spring 4.0 introduced `@RestController`, a specialized version of the controller which is a convenience annotation that does nothing more than add the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations. By annotating the controller class with `@RestController` annotation, you no longer need to add `@ResponseBody` to all the request mapping methods. The `@ResponseBody` annotation is active by default. Click here to learn more.

```
@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody
```

Answer (score 0):

@RestController
public class DemoController {

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "userdetails",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
public UserInfo getUserDetails(@RequestBody Principal principal){
    return users.get(principal.getName());
}
```

}

other way work around

Answer (score -1):

Remove the @ResponseBody annotation from the method.

Comment: Still getting the same result :(